# Redmineで管理者以外で特定のプラグインが有効にならない

Tags: redmine

Heroku上にRedmine環境を構築し、Ajileプラグインを導入した状態でデプロイし、運用しております。
https://www.redmineup.com/pages/plugins/agile

システム管理者でログインしている間は、プロジェクトのタブにAjile表示がされるのですが、一般アカウントでログインするとAjileタブが表示されずにプラグインが使用できず困ってます。

以下を試しました。

①一般アカウントをシステム管理者に設定しログインする。
-> Ajileタブが表示され機能が使用できました。その後、システム管理者設定を解除し、ログインしたところ、Ajileタブが非表示となり機能が使用不可となりました。

②新しく一般アカウントを追加し、ログインする。
-> Ajileタブが表示されず、機能使用不可でした（既存アカウントと同じ）。

Redmineプラグインのユーザー毎の切り替えは無い認識ですが、実際にそのような動作になってしまっており、困っています。
どなたか詳しい方いらしたらご教授頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: 新規のアジャイルボードを作るときに `to me only` を選択していませんか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。いえ、プロジェクト作成時にモジュールでAjileにチェックボックスを入れるとそのプロジェクトのタブにAjileが表示されるのですが、そのタブ自体が表示されないのです。プラグイン自体が無効になっている様子です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

すいません。自己解決しました。プラグインの設定と、ユーザーの設定の箇所だけを見ていたのですが、Ajileプラグインはプロジェクトのロール毎にON/OFFが切り替えられる様子で、各担当のデフォルトが全てOFFだった為に表示されなかったみたいです。お騒がせしました。

Answer (score 0):

私も同じ事象でハマり、[この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/42759)同様ロール毎にON/OFFを切り替えることで解決しました。
ありがとうございました。

操作は、管理＞ロールと権限　から対象のロールを選択すると、
権限の中に「Agile」が存在し、以下の4つのチェックボックスがあります。
　□Manage public agile boards
　□Add agile boards
　□View agile boards
　□View agile charts